# Find non-numeric values in pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dtype

I got a a column in a dataframe that contains numbers and strings. So I replaced the strings by numbers via `df.column.replace(["A", "B", "C", "D"], [1, 2, 3, 4], inplace=True)`.

But the column is still dtype "object". I can not sort the column (TypeError error: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int').

Now how can I identify those numbers that are strings? I tried `print(df[pd.to_numeric(df['column']).isnull()])` and it gives back an empty dataframe, as expected. However I read that this does not work in my case (actual numbers saved as strings). So how can I identify those numbers saved as a string?

Am I right that if a column only contains REAL numbers (int or float) it will automatically change to dtype int or float?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post the dataframe to the question? You can [edit] the question and update it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can change dtype

```
    df.column.dtype=df.column.astype(int)
```

Comment: It says: "AttributeError: can't set attribute"... I think that there are strings but how is it possible to find them?

Comment: print(set(df.column))  it  will  show  unique values so you can find  what are the strings added  with  numeric values

Comment: Ok, as i guessed there are some strings and floats (e. g. '1' or 5.0): {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, '1', 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 14, 23, '3', 25, 27, 28, 26, 30, 31, 32, 33, 29, 35, 36, 38, 39, 40, 42, '17', '27', '11', '2', '9', '7', '4', 99, '6', -1, 24, '5', -2} With df.column = df.column.astype(int) I could solve the problem, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Francesco's answer, it's possible to create a mask of non-numeric values and identify unique instances to handle or remove.
This uses the fact that where values cant be coerced, they are treated as nulls.

```
is_non_numeric = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').isnull()
df[is_non_numeric]['column'].unique()
```

Or alternatively in a single line:

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce').isnull()]['column'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.to_numeric` with something like:

```
df['column'] = pd.to_numeric(df['column'], errors='coerce')
```

For the `errors` argument you have few option, see reference documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)